# Is there a way to increase resistance of a resistor with an outside current?

Tags: resistors, resistance, components

First of all, I know (correct me if I am wrong) that variable resistors are a thing, but my problem with them is that they only work because they have hundreds of little resistors inside.

I was wondering if there was a way to increase resistance of one line if I had a second line with current that increased its resistance.

Like:

```
        A
        |
        |
        /
B______ \ ______
        /
        \
        |
        |
```

Keep in mind the resistance should increase with current.

B goes into resistor A to increase its resistance.

I thought of two possible solutions, let me know your thoughts on them.

1. If B's current was about 10x more than A's, could it heat up the resistor? I know heat causes added resistance. If I wrapped B around the resistor but didn't connect it, it could transfer heat (under the right circumstances).
2. My second thought was adding like a crossroads, where it would slow down, because more electrons were bumping into each other, like a 4-way intersection in traffic. However, I don't understand how to make B go one way, and not with A, or vice versa.

Comment: I mean, technically, you could make the resistor out of the same material as a thermistor which has a very large temperature coefficient and apply a heating coil around it. But without feedback and control systems it won't be stable and it won't be linear.

Comment: The application is critical. There are different solutions depending on the power level, range, noise, linearity, steppiness, stability, speed, required. For instance, FETs make good variable resistors for audio attenuators, and there are ways to reduce the distortion that a single one has. Switched capacitors can behave like resistors, and are the basis of a large number of circuits that would otherwise use programmable resistors. If the resistor is to control a voltage or current, then generally there are better ways to do that directly. Share the precise application for better suggestions.

Comment: Some good ideas suggested, but without knowing your intended application, some won't work. Please improve your question by telling us **how you intend to use this variable resistor**. There are even more ways to do variable R, but perhaps not for your  specific application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, I know (correct me if I am wrong) that variable resistors are a thing, but my problem with them is that they only work because they have hundreds if little resistors inside.

Variable resistors work by physically moving a contact over a resistive material. The less material between the moving contact and the fixed contact, the smaller the resistance.

The resistivity of the material, \$\rho\$, is an innate property that describes how much electrical resistance the material has per unit length and cross-sectional area. The relationship is:

$$R=\frac {\rho L} {A}$$

Where \$R\$ is the resistance, \$\rho\$ is the material resistivity, \$L\$ is the length of the material in meters, and \$A\$ is the cross-sectional area in square meters.

For a variable resistor made out of a single material with a fixed shape and size, \$\rho\$ and \$A\$ are constant. Therefore, the resistance you get is linearly proportional to the length of the material. By moving one contact across the material while another contact is fixed, you change the effective length of the material, and therefore the resistance.

> I was wondering if there was a way to increase resistance of one line of line, if I had a second line with current that increased it's resistance.

That's effectively what a BJT transistor does. The current flowing between the collector and emitter is roughly equal to the base current multiplied by the gain (beta value, or hFE) of the transistor.

More formally, for an NPN BJT, the current flow is described by:

$$I_{CE}=I_B \times h_{FE}$$

Here is an example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJRIUT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The \$h_{FE}\$ value for the 2N2222 is 100. The base current, \$I_B\$, is 1mA, so the current through the emitter and collector, \$I_{CE}\$, is roughly 100mA. As \$I_B\$ increases, \$I_{CE}\$ also increases, as if the "resistance" of the transistor was decreasing.

A PNP transistor operates the same way, but the direction of current flow is reversed.

You can achieve a similar effect using a variable voltage on the gate of a MOSFET operating in the linear (or "ohmic") region. For an N-channel MOSFET, the effective \$R_{DS(on)}\$ decreases as the \$V_{GS}\$ decreases. For a P-channel MOSFET, the effective \$R_{DS(on)}\$ increases as the \$V_{GS}\$ decreases. Extra care must be taken with this approach due to the nonlinear relationship between \$V_{GS}\$ and \$I_{DS}\$; pushing the gate voltage too far will cause the MOSFET to enter the saturation region and the conductance to sharply rise.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! Right now I have one question, do electric variable resistors do what uou described? I know potentiometers (at least the type with the turning end) do, but was wondering if electrical resistors actually had moving parts.

Comment: Is there an image that shows what the insides of a variable resistor looks like?

Comment: digital potentiometers resistors literally have hundreds of little resistors inside them.

Comment: @Jasen That is what I thouht, so I was wondering if Polynomial had a different thing in mind.

Comment: @Walter You can probably find one on Google Images.

Comment: @Walter A digital potentiometer is a device that has an analog multiplexer/switch that can select different resistors, but since you didn't mention a _digital_ potentiometer and only seemed to be talking about variable resistors and current-driven devices, I didn't mention the programmable option.

Comment: @Polynomial So which type of resistor were you talking about that had the behavior you described at the beginning?

Comment: @Walter A regular potentiometer. The type you physically actuate (rotation or slide).

Comment: @Polynomial ok thank you, and i think the transistor thing is genious with gain. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There are ways, see "carbon amplifier" and "magnetic amplifier" and "vactrol" for examples.

(well magnetic amplifier is technically a variable inductance, but it's used like a resistor)

This latter is probably the easiest for the home experimenter, you'll need a photoconductor and an electric light source.

I used a NSL-4132  CdS light dependant resistor and an ordinary 20mA red LED.

Put the LED next to the LDR so that it shines on the sensitive surface, wrap the pair in something light-proof, then vary the LED current change the conductivity of the LDR.

These have fallen out of popularity as it's usually easier to perform the task in some cheaper way.

Comment: Note that vactrols are illegal to use in most any products you intend to sell in the EU (and likely many other places too), due to their cadmium (a toxic heavy metal much like lead or mercury) content. I am unsure about their legal status when used for personal projects, but likely not as much of a concern.

Comment: hmm, it's allowed in infrared and x-ray detectors, just not for visible light.

Answer (score 0):

[Motor driven potentiometers](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/54/psl-1280324.pdf) are available, in slide and [rotary](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/54/PRM16-778060.pdf) types and in B linear and audio tapers.

You would have to build a servo amplifier and devote one of the tracks to feedback to make it directly voltage-controlled or current-controlled.